# How can I securely allow web users to create files?

Tags: php, linux, apache, file-permissions

I'm building a website which allows certain users to write reviews, and I want a small php file to be automatically generated when they do. What's the most secure way to set up accounts/groups/file permissions to allow this? Ideally, I'd like the review writers to be able to change the title in case they make a mistake, which would require php to be able to not only create files and folders, but move and/or remove them, as well. However, that's not an absolute necessity. My test server is running Linux/Apache, the newest versions of everything, and for testing purposes I've temporarily set the owner of the main reviews folder as the server. I'm also open to other suggestions on how to make this happen. I'm not really an IT guy, but I can write shell scripts just fine.

Edit:

Thanks to the selected answer, I was able to come up with a solution. I used this guide (http://www.seomoz.org/ugc/using-mod-rewrite-to-convert-dynamic-urls-to-seo-friendly-urls), and modified it to just load the desired php script with no variables, which I designed to retrieve the information directly from the original URL using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. Here's what my .htaccess file looks like; It sends `www.domain.com/reviews/the-review-filepath.php` to `www.domain.com/reviews/review.php`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !^review\.php$ review.php
```

It was much easier for me to do it this way because I a lot more about PHP than regular expressions.
Thanks to everyone who answered and/or commented. This is much better than the way I was trying to do it before.

Comment: Why are you using the file system for this instead of a proper database such as MySQL?

Comment: Maxwell is right. You need to use a database for this.

Comment: I have a database which contains all the review data, however I decided it was best for SEO to have a placeholder file which calls a script which generates the page based on the review number in the placeholder file. I feel it is necessary to have these files in place, even if I have to personally create them, without automation.

Comment: @knoell8504 That makes no sense whatsoever. A search engine crawling your page has no way of knowing if the content is being grabbed out of a file or database.

Comment: Search results are much more likely (2.5 times is what I've heard) to be clicked if the urls are clean and the important data is in the filepath, not some variable. And crawlers have made improvements at interpreting things like GET variables, but still not quite as good as actual filepaths. At least, that's what I've gathered.

Comment: @knoell8504 Use mod_rewrite (since you tagged [tag:Apache]) for that matter...

Comment: @knoell8504 You can pass variables with clean urls. Look at the URL you are on right now for StackOverflow. It is using a clean url to get info out of a database.

Comment: @Passerby Thanks, I think that's exactly what I'm looking for. So I'll use that so the reviews can be mapped without variables, and have the URL rewritten with the variables. Put that as an answer, and I'll select it. It's exactly on topic to my question.

Comment: @Maxwell Yes, stackoverflow uses a variable in the URL, but if you remove the variable, it still takes you to this exact same page, it just doesn't focus on the comment. Their strategy is the very same strategy I'm attempting to implement. I'm betting they do it the way Passerby suggested, with mod_rewrite or something similar.

Comment: @knoell8504 Really? If you take the variable "15331339" out of the URL you are on right now it still takes you here?

Comment: @Maxwell The GET variables are what comes after the "?" with the following syntax: thewebsite.com/filepath?variablename=variablevalue (and this URL also has a #hash. I guess I should have specified removing the variable AND the hash.)
So the variable in this URL is "noredirect=1", not "15331339". 15331339 may be a variable to the server, but from the perspective of our browser, and any bot, it is part of the filepath.

Comment: @knoell8504 Yes, I know what GET variables are. What you said after that, however, is wrong. "15331339" is absolutely a variable. Something can be a variable without being passed explicitly as a GET or POST variable by the client.

Comment: I believe that's what I said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending from comment:

If you want to get a "clean" url (e.g. `/post/123/comment/456`) instead of "parameterized" url (e.g. `/?post=123&comment=456`), you can still use database, and take advantage of [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) (since you tagged [apache](/questions/tagged/apache)).